# Fatal error when launching exe (involves pyqt5, importlib, and subprocess

Tags: python, pyqt5, subprocess, pyinstaller, import-module

I've prepared a simple script, GUI_Test.py, using pyqt5 (and QtDesigner) to illustrate my two errors. My directories are set up as follows:

```
C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\GUI_test > GUI_Test.py
                              > modules > var.py
                              > processes > A1.py
```

Here's the GUI_Test.py script (it's just one button and one label):

```
import sys
import os
import subprocess
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from importlib import import_module

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def __init__(self, MainWindow):
        super().__init__()
    
        # Build the interface
        self.setupUi(MainWindow)
    
        # Variables
        self.count = 0
        self.main_dir = sys.path[0]
        self.outfile = self.main_dir + "\\output.txt"
        self.module_path = self.main_dir + "\\modules\\var.py"
        self.processes_dir = self.main_dir + "\\processes\\"
    
        # Initialize outfile
        with open(self.outfile, 'w') as f:
            f.write('')
    
        # Defining button functionality
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.button1_handler)
    
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(273, 137)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.button1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 10, 101, 41))
        self.button1.setObjectName("button1")
        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 50, 101, 41))
        self.label1.setObjectName("label1")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 273, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "GUI_Test"))
        self.button1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Run"))
        self.label1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", ""))

    def button1_handler(self):
        ### Test 1 - Updating label and writing to .txt file ### #------------ This works!
        self.count += 1
        self.label1.setText("Test {0}".format(self.count))
    
        with open(self.outfile, 'a') as f:
            f.write("Test {0}\n".format(self.count))
        ##################
    
        ### Test 2 - Importing modules ### #------------ This doesn't work when launching .exe!
        head, tail = os.path.split(self.module_path)
        trim_tail = os.path.splitext(tail)[0]
        sys.path.insert(1, head) # places the desired dir in the correct place for import_module
        varMod = import_module(trim_tail)
    
        with open(self.outfile, 'a') as f:
            f.write("{0}\n".format(varMod.x))
        ##################
    
        ### Test 3 - Using subprocess.run ### #------------ This doesn't work when launching .exe!
        for file in os.scandir(self.processes_dir):
            result = subprocess.run([sys.executable, file.path], capture_output=True, text=True)
            if result.stderr:
                with open(self.outfile, 'a') as f:
                    f.write("{0}\n\n".format(result.stderr))
            else:
                with open(self.outfile, 'a') as f:
                    f.write("{0}\n\n".format(result.stdout))
        ##################
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here's the var.py script:

```
x = "Imported variable"
```

Here's the A1.py script:

```
name = "Joe"
print(name)
```

To convert from GUI_Test.py to GUI_Test.exe, I navigate to cmd and execute the following:

```
C:\Users\Dan\Desktop\GUI_test>pyinstaller --onefile --windowed GUI_Test.py
```

This builds successfully with no errors. When I open GUI_Test.exe I get: "Fatal error detected: Failed to execute script GUI_Test". If I comment out tests 2 and 3 (found under the button1_handler) the exe launches and runs just fine. If I introduce Test 2 into the fold, I get the fatal error. If I comment out Test 2 and now use Test 3, I get the fatal error. So it appears I have two errors (tests 2 and 3) that are potentially independent of each other. I can't seem to determine the error(s). Note that this script runs/works just fine as GUI_Test.py. The errors only occur when running the executable GUI_Test.exe.

Comment: Why not importing `var.py` and `A1.py` regularly: `import var.py` ? When you are building an exe dynamic imports doesn't make much sense. `pyinstaller` extracts the exe into a temporary directory, so `var.py` is not found in `sys.path[0]`.

Comment: In my real application, var.py is the solutions to A1.py, where A1.py would be submitted by a student (let's say). So the idea was for the user to select which key (var.py) to use and which assignment (A1.py) to auto-mark; i.e., I'd like the user to select both files. Only var.py requires importing. Do you know of a way to maintain this desired feature, while still using pyinstaller?